# Install Hadoop MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, hadoop

I am trying to run "hstart" command to check that I have well installed Hadoop.
I get the following errors:

```
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 9767
Starting datanodes
localhost: WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME.      Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 9871
Starting secondary namenodes [MacBook-Pro-de-Alice.local]
MacBook-Pro-de-Alice.local: WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced   by HADOOP_HOME. Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
MacBook-Pro-de-Alice.local: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 10006
2018-12-27 00:22:05,379 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load       native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: WARNING: HADOOP_PREFIX has been replaced by HADOOP_HOME.    Using value of HADOOP_PREFIX.
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 10301
```

Any idea at where I should look? I followed (http://hanslen.me/2018/01/19/How-to-install-Hadoop-on-macOS-High-Sierra/) for the installation process, and I am wondering if it might be an error due to my using Mojave?

Comment: Sounds like you're using Hadoop3, which that blog is not using. Try following the official Apache Hadoop site for configuration (after brew install or just downloading the tarball)